# how do I locate cause of errors in BindingResult

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc web application using hibernate in eclipse and tomcat server, I changed a couple of text fields to drop down lists in a jsp, so that a person's gender and race can each be selected from its own drop down menu.  I was careful to change other levels of the application, including setting up joined tables for gender and race in the underlying database, and changing code in the model and repository levels.  The application compiles, and the jsp loads with the correct selected values for the selected person in each dropdown list, but clicking the submit/update button causes a BindingResult.hasErrors() problem which does not help me localize the cause of the problem.

Can someone help me find the cause of the failure to process the update?

Here is the processUpdatePatientForm() method that is called in the controller class.  Note that it triggers the System.out.println() which shows that BindingResult.hasErrors() and returns the jsp:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String processUpdatePatientForm(@Valid Patient patient, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::: in PatientController.processUpdatePatientForm() result.hasErrors() ");
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        for(int i=0;i<result.getErrorCount();i++){System.out.println("]]]]]]] error "+i+" is: "+errors.get(i).toString());}
        return "patients/createOrUpdatePatientForm";} 
    else {
        this.clinicService.savePatient(patient);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/patients?patientID=" + patient.getId();
    }
}
```

When the jsp is returned, the following error messages are included:

```
//This is printed out in my jsp below the Sex drop down list:  
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Gender for property sex; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Gender] for property sex: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

//This is printed out in my jsp below the Race drop down list:  
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Race for property race; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Race] for property race: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

The following is all that is printed in the eclipse console:

```
Hibernate: select gender0_.id as id1_2_, gender0_.name as name2_2_ from gender gender0_ order by gender0_.name
Hibernate: select race0_.id as id1_7_, race0_.name as name2_7_ from race race0_ order by race0_.name
:::::::::::::::: in PatientController.processUpdatePatientForm() result.hasErrors() 
]]]]]]] error 0 is: Field error in object 'patient' on field 'race': rejected value [Hispanic]; codes [typeMismatch.patient.race,typeMismatch.race,typeMismatch.org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Race,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [patient.race,race]; arguments []; default message [race]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Race' for property 'race'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Race] for property 'race': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
]]]]]]] error 1 is: Field error in object 'patient' on field 'sex': rejected value [Male]; codes [typeMismatch.patient.sex,typeMismatch.sex,typeMismatch.org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Gender,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [patient.sex,sex]; arguments []; default message [sex]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Gender' for property 'sex'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.Gender] for property 'sex': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

**Note that the values [Hispanic] and [Male] are shown in the error message as triggering the error. The problem might be that the name property of Gender and Race is being passed to Spring MVC, when the id property should be passed instead. But how do I fix this in the code?**

Can someone help me get to the bottom of this?  The first step would be how can I get a more useful error message which locates the location in my code where the problem is being triggered.

---

### EDIT:

Per Sotirios's request, the following is my form in the jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="patient" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal" id="add-patient-form">
    <petclinic:inputField label="First Name" name="firstName"/>
    <petclinic:inputField label="Middle Initial" name="middleInitial"/>
    <petclinic:inputField label="Last Name" name="lastName"/>

    <div class="control-group">
        <petclinic:selectField label="Sex" name="sex" names="${genders}" size="5"/>
    </div>

    <petclinic:inputField label="Date of Birth" name="dateOfBirth"/>

    <div class="control-group">
        <petclinic:selectField label="Race" name="race" names="${races}" size="5"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${patient['new']}">
                <button type="submit">Add Patient</button>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <button type="submit">Update Patient</button>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

And the Patient.java class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patients")
public class Patient extends BaseEntity {

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Document> documents;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Address> addresses;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient",  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers;

@Column(name = "first_name")
@NotEmpty
protected String firstName;

@Column(name = "middle_initial")
protected String middleInitial;

@Column(name = "last_name")
@NotEmpty
protected String lastName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sex_id")
protected Gender sex;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
protected DateTime dateOfBirth;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "race_id")
protected Race race;

////////////// Document methods
protected void setDocumentsInternal(Set<Document> documents) {this.documents = documents;}

public Set<Document> getFaxes() {
    Set<Document> faxes = new HashSet<Document>();
    for (Document doc : getDocumentsInternal()) {if (doc.getType().getName().equals("ScannedFaxes")) {faxes.add(doc);}}
    return faxes;
}
public Set<Document> getForms() {
    Set<Document> forms = new HashSet<Document>();
    for (Document doc : getDocumentsInternal()) {if (doc.getType().getName().equals("ScannedPatientForms")) {forms.add(doc);}}
    return forms;
}

protected Set<Document> getDocumentsInternal() {
    if (this.documents == null) {this.documents = new HashSet<Document>();}
    return this.documents;
}

public List<Document> getDocuments() {
    List<Document> sortedDocuments = new ArrayList<Document>(getDocumentsInternal());
    PropertyComparator.sort(sortedDocuments, new MutableSortDefinition("name", true, true));
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedDocuments);
}

public void addDocument(Document doc) {
    getDocumentsInternal().add(doc);
    doc.setPatient(this);
}

public Document getDocument(String name) {return getDocument(name, false);}

/** Return the Document with the given name, or null if none found for this Patient.
 * @param name to test
 * @return true if document name is already in use
 */
public Document getDocument(String name, boolean ignoreNew) {
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    for (Document doc : getDocumentsInternal()) {
        if (!ignoreNew || !doc.isNew()) {
            String compName = doc.getName();
            compName = compName.toLowerCase();
            if (compName.equals(name)) {
                return doc;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//////////// Address methods
protected void setAddressesInternal(Set<Address> addresses) {this.addresses = addresses;}

protected Set<Address> getAddressesInternal() {
    if (this.addresses == null) {this.addresses = new HashSet<Address>();}
    return this.addresses;
}

public List<Address> getAddresses() {
    List<Address> sortedAddresses = new ArrayList<Address>(getAddressesInternal());
    PropertyComparator.sort(sortedAddresses, new MutableSortDefinition("address", true, true));
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedAddresses);
}

public void addAddress(Address addr) {
    getAddressesInternal().add(addr);
    addr.setPatient(this);
}

public Address getAddress(String address) {return getAddress(address, false);}

/** Return the Address with the given name, or null if none found for this Patient.
 * @param name to test
 * @return true if document name is already in use
 */
public Address getAddress(String addr, boolean ignoreNew) {
    addr = addr.toLowerCase();
    for (Address address1 : getAddressesInternal()) {
        if (!ignoreNew || !address1.isNew()) {
            String compName = address1.getAddress();
            compName = compName.toLowerCase();
            if (compName.equals(addr)) {
                return address1;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
//////////// PhoneNumber methods
protected void setPhoneNumbersInternal(Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers) {this.phonenumbers = phonenumbers;}

protected Set<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbersInternal() {
    if (this.phonenumbers == null) {this.phonenumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();}
    return this.phonenumbers;
}

public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
    List<PhoneNumber> sortedPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>(getPhoneNumbersInternal());
    PropertyComparator.sort(sortedPhoneNumbers, new MutableSortDefinition("phonenumber", true, true));
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(sortedPhoneNumbers);
}

public void addPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber pn) {
    getPhoneNumbersInternal().add(pn);
    pn.setPatient(this);
}

public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber(String pn) {return getPhoneNumber(pn, false);}

/** Return the PhoneNumber with the given name, or null if none found for this Patient.
 * @param name to test
 * @return true if phone number is already in use
 */
public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber(String pn, boolean ignoreNew) {
    pn = pn.toLowerCase();
    for (PhoneNumber number : getPhoneNumbersInternal()) {
        if (!ignoreNew || !number.isNew()) {
            String compName = number.getPhonenumber();
            compName = compName.toLowerCase();
            if (compName.equals(pn)) {
                return number;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String getFirstName(){return this.firstName;}
public void setFirstName(String firstName){this.firstName = firstName;}

public String getMiddleInitial() {return this.middleInitial;}
public void setMiddleInitial(String middleinitial) {this.middleInitial = middleinitial;}

public String getLastName() {return this.lastName;}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {this.lastName = lastName;}

public Gender getSex() {return this.sex;}
public void setSex(Gender sex) {this.sex = sex;}

public void setDateOfBirth(DateTime birthDate){this.dateOfBirth = birthDate;}
public DateTime getDateOfBirth(){return this.dateOfBirth;}

public Race getRace() {return this.race;}
public void setRace(Race race) {this.race = race;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringCreator(this)
            .append("id", this.getId())
            .append("new", this.isNew())
            .append("lastName", this.getLastName())
            .append("firstName", this.getFirstName())
            .append("middleinitial", this.getMiddleInitial())
            .append("dateofbirth", this.dateOfBirth)
            .toString();
}
}
```

---

### SECOND EDIT:

Per Alexey's comment, the following is the method in the controller class which has always had the @InitBinder annotation.  It is identical to a method in the controller of a similar module which works:

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");}
```

---

### THIRD EDIT:

PatientController.java:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(types = Patient.class)
public class PatientController {

private final ClinicService clinicService;

@Autowired
public PatientController(ClinicService clinicService) {this.clinicService = clinicService;}

@ModelAttribute("genders")
public Collection<Gender> populateGenders() {return this.clinicService.findGenders();}

@ModelAttribute("races")
public Collection<Race> populateRaces() {return this.clinicService.findRaces();}

@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Patient patient = new Patient();
    model.put("patient", patient);
    return "patients/createOrUpdatePatientForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processCreationForm(@Valid Patient patient, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {return "patients/createOrUpdatePatientForm";}
    else {
        this.clinicService.savePatient(patient);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/patients?patientID=" + patient.getId();
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(@RequestParam("patientID") String patientId, Patient patient, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Collection<Patient> results = this.clinicService.findPatientByLastName("");
    model.put("selections", results);
    int patntId = Integer.parseInt(patientId);
    Patient sel_patient = this.clinicService.findPatientById(patntId);//I added this
    model.put("sel_patient",sel_patient);
    return "patients/patientsList";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initUpdatePatientForm(@PathVariable("patientId") int patientId, Model model) {
    Patient patient = this.clinicService.findPatientById(patientId);
    model.addAttribute(patient);
    return "patients/createOrUpdatePatientForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String processUpdatePatientForm(@Valid Patient patient, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::: in PatientController.processUpdatePatientForm() result.hasErrors() ");
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        for(int i=0;i<result.getErrorCount();i++){System.out.println("]]]]]]] error "+i+" is: "+errors.get(i).toString());}
        return "patients/createOrUpdatePatientForm";} 
    else {
        this.clinicService.savePatient(patient);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/patients?patientID=" + patient.getId();
    }
}
}
```

---

### FOURTH EDIT:

Gender.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gender")
public class Gender extends NamedEntity {}
```

NamedEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class NamedEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public String getName() {return this.name;}

@Override
public String toString() {return this.getName();}

}
```

BaseEntity.java:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Integer id;

public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}

public Integer getId() {return id;}

public boolean isNew() {return (this.id == null);}

}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you.  I just posted form and Patient.  I also added a system.out.println() that iterates through the errors with more detail.  Does this show you where the error is?  What should I change?

Comment: `Race`? Seriously? In the 21st century?

Comment: @zeroflagL Would you prefer the term ethnicity? I just thought race was shorter and more inclusive.  Are you willing to answer my question?

Comment: I would prefer to have the field removed entirely ;) Ethnicity is at least a term that actually can be applied to humans :) Race is only applicable to certain kinds of animals. There already was a correct answer, as far as I remember. What was wrong with it? And can you please add the code for the `Gender` class?

Comment: @zeroflagL I just added Gender.java and the two other classes from which it is derived.  Is there anything else you need to find the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a converter or a proper editor. I prefer the first one. Refer to section 6.5. on [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) for the details.

Your converter would have to get the Entity with the given name from the database and return it. The code would be something like this:

```
class StringToGender implements Converter<String, Gender> {
  @Autowired
  private GenderRepository repository;

  public Gender convert(String name) {
    return repository.getGenderByName(name);
  }
}
```

And in your application context xml (if you use xml):

```
    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.example.StringToGender"/>
        </set>
    </property>
```